# Use values that are in all arrays and skip the rest

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with 3 sub arrays like:

```
$array = array(
    width => array(
        0 => 1,
        1 => 2,
        2 => 3,
        3 => 4,
        4 => 5
    ),
    height => array(
        0 => 1,
        1 => 2,
        2 => 7,
        3 => 8
    ),
    color => array(
        0 => 2,
        1 => 7,
        2 => 8
    )
);
```

The count is in this case 3 as I have 3 arrays. This can be sometimes more or less, that's why I have a count.

Now I want to find out which number is in all 3 arrays and only use those. in above example the only returned number should be 2 as it's present in all 3 sub arrays.

I was trying something like below, but am really stuck what's the best approach...

```
$i = count($array); // gives me back the count of 3 which is correct
$n = 0;
foreach($array as $key=>values) {
    foreach($values as $value) {
        // do not how to proceed :(
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `array_intersect` with all the sub-arrays as arguments.

```
$common_values = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can affect your rows in some `var` and make what you want to do in your `foreach`

Like :

```
<?php

$width = 0;
$height = 0;
$color = 0 ;

$arrayBundleWidth = array();
$arrayBundleHeight = array();
$arrayBundleColor = array();

foreach ($array as $arrayRow){
   $arrayBundleWidth = $arrayRow['width'];
   $arrayBundleColor = $arrayRow['color'];
   $arrayBundleHeight = $arrayRow['height'];

   foreach ($arrayBundleWidth as $arrayBundleWidthtRow) {
    # code...
    #you got each index of your width array here
   }
   foreach ($arrayBundleHeight as $arrayBundleHeightRow) {
    # code...
    #you got each index of your height array here
   }
   foreach ($arrayBundleColor as $arrayBundleColorRow) {
    # code...
    #you got each index of your color array here
   }
}

?>
```

Try it and tell me ? Is it what you want ?
Not sure if it's what you wanted to do !